# Is possible to publish web application mvc 4 (template 4.5.2) on iis7 using file system as publishing method since vs 2015?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7, visual-studio-2015

The application in local environment runs well, but when it's published 
on live web server displays

```
The resource cannot be found. 
 Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Yes, it is possible.

However the default page is not defined in web.config. It must be specified in RouteConfig.cs inside of App_Start directory. Something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id  =   UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

As you can see, the absolute path is without cshtml extension, so could  be put in url browser something like:

http://server:prort/Account/Login